# width 100% on top of body requires scrolling

Tags: html, css, scalability

I want a div to go across the page width no matter the size of one's screen. The problem I'm having is that although the width is 100%, when I view the page it requires scrolling horizontally. I've looked up solutions and tried the suggestions regarding the body element, but I still have this issue. Here are my body and div elements:

```
body{
    background-color: #9F6164;
    margin:0px;
    margin-top: .6em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding:0px;
}

#controlpanel {
    height:8em;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#F8DEBD;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    border-bottom: 3px groove black;
    float:center;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

To be clear this is not homework, I'm doing this for a personal project.

Comment: So you don't want the horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: That's correct. I want the div to perfectly fit the body without horizontal scroll, regardless of monitor size

Comment: `overflow-x:hidden` is often a solution, a bad one but still a solution

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is 100% width, but the browser also adds 1em of padding to it, so it's now 100% + 1em. You didn't set the box-sizing property and it's content-box by default.

If you want your layout to behave more naturally, add this to your code:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/avyxhfcp/

BTW: there is no "float: center;"

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the horizontal overflow using `overflow-x`. You could also use `overflow:hidden`, but the code below specifically targets horizontal scroll bar.

```
body {
    background-color: #9F6164;
    margin:0px;
    margin-top: .6em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding:0px;
    overflow-x:hidden;  /* hide the horizontal overflow */
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution cosmonot provided is incorrect and will only cause you problems when your div's content stretches off-screen and you can no longer troubleshoot when there are overflow problems because you won't be able to see a scrollbar horizontally.

The real problem is that your div is using width: 100% to occupy the entire horizontal space available, it is then adding on the padding you specified as extra, this results in the overall width being over 100% which breaks out the body element giving overflow and thus making it horizontally scroll able.

The solution is not to alter your body's overflow property, the solution is to apply box-sizing: border-box; to your control panel div. This will make the width you specify **include** the padding and margin's you specify.

Example

```
#controlpanel {
    height:8em;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#F8DEBD;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    border-bottom: 3px groove black;
    float:center;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

In future try not to play around with the body, it's usually what you put into it that needs to be troubleshooted.

Comment: @skiesareforflying follow the suggestion on this answer. What I provided was a quick trick, but not a proper solution.

Comment: We don't have float:center at this point